# jquery .data function vs setting data value in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-data

in jquery if i use `$("#my_button").data('my-value', { onClick: function () { my_obj_function(); } });`

and in another function i do this

`my-value.onClick.call()` it works.

but if i try to set the data attrib in html it not working.
i did this in html
`<a href='#' data-my-value='{"onClick":"function () { my_obj_function(); }"}'>Click me</a>`

while `calling my-value.onClick.call()` i'm getting 
`uncaught typeerror : object function() has no method call`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: As per the HTML5 custom attributes specification, `<a ... data-my-value="..." ...>` is equivalent to `$(...).data('myValue')`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis - Not really. The `.data()` method can _retrieve_ html5 `data-` attributes, but it can't _set_ them. `data-` attributes are strings, but `.data()` can store other types including objects.

Comment: @nnnnnn - True. I understand that `$.cache` is used by jQuery to handle `data()`, but I thought it was worth mentioning the slight disconnect between the data key and the attribute Rifky was using.

Comment: @Phylogenesis - Ah. Right, sorry. (A disconnect of my own.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set a value with `.data()` it does **not** set an html attribute on the element, jQuery stores it in its own data structure. That's why you can use `.data()` to store functions and other objects. `.data()` *can* be used to *retrieve* html5 `data-` attributes, but not set them.

When you have an html attribute it is just a string so you'd need to `eval()` it or parse it somehow and pass to `new Function()`. This is not the way to go.

Having said that, I don't see how `my-value.onClick.call()` could possibly work, given that it is actually saying `my` minus `value.onClick.call()`. Assuming you had set the value with `.data()` you could say `$("#my_button").data('my-value').onClick.call()`...

If you want to set a `data-` attribute with jQuery you can use the `.attr()` method instead of `.data()`, with `$("#my_button").attr('data-my-value', ...)`, but as already mentioned this will set it as a string.

Comment: So that mean i cannot set object in a data atribute in HTML :-(

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
<a href='#' data-my-value='{"onClick":"function () { my_obj_function(); }"}'>Click me</a>
```

is setting it as a string and not as an object.

Comment: Is there any other alternative way to set function or object as data value in html?

Comment: you can do an `eval` but that is dangerous